# Qt: Custom slots not working

Tags: c++, qt

So i have a custom class extending QWidget. I have tried adding a custom slot to it. However it keeps giving me the error:

```
"QObject::connect: No such slot QWidget::closeSlot() in ..\menuTest\menu.cpp:13".
```

My code is:

```
#include "menu.h"

Menu::Menu()
{
    exitButton = new QPushButton;
    exitButton->setText(tr("Exit"));

    connect(exitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(closeSlot()));

    QVBoxLayout * layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(exitButton);
    this->setLayout(layout);
}

void Menu::closeSlot()
{
    qDebug() << "I'm inside";
}
```

and the header file:

```
#ifndef MENU_H
#define MENU_H

#include "allIncludes.h"

class Menu : public QWidget
{
public:
    Menu();

private:
QPushButton * exitButton;

private slots:
    void closeSlot();
};

#endif // MENU_H
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a class to be recognised by Qt's meta-object system, it must include the `Q_OBJECT` macro:

```
class Menu : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Menu();

private:
QPushButton * exitButton;

private slots:
    void closeSlot();
};
```

Comment: And don't forget to run `qmake` after adding the `Q_OBJECT` macro.

Comment: @PrisonMonkeys Or, more generally, `moc`. (If you're not using `qmake`, for example). But at least the linker will complain if you don't.